# Illustration Isolation and Clipping Groups

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]I'm a bit stuck here.

I only want to click on one part of a character's body. Every time I try to click on one it just them clicks on the whole body

I also have this on clipping group and isolation. Do you know how to get this off?

Please help. 
thanks [image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say 'body'?

Comment: hiya, just added a picture there. Seems to be when I click on one part, it clicks the whole thing.

Comment: and I just don't know how to get rid of the clip groups.  think that has something to do with it :/

Comment: You'll probably need to recreate these gradients. Is this an original file you created with Illustrator or does it comes from somewhere else? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53127/how-can-i-simplify-this-object-with-excessive-clipping-mask/54960#54960

Comment: I made some of it at college and continued at home. I started going like this when I was doing it at home

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow) if you wish to only select one object within a group.

You've got all those clip groups because it appears as though you created a bunch of objects with a Bristle Brush, then they were expanded - either manually or due to some other operation you've performed - so this has created a whole slew of embedded raster images masked with clipping masks, making up a "clip group".